# If I move my btc (private key), from Ledger to Bitcoin Core

Tags: bitcoin-core

.... can I still use my 24 word seed phrase (from when I setup Ledger wallet), to access those coins on the blockchain?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So I would need to extract private key through Bitcoin Core?

Answer (score 1):

To use a 24 word backup phrase / seed phrase, you would need to install wallet software that is designed to be able to import that type of phrase. Most use a type of phrase defined by BIP39 - But some wallets use a different incompatible scheme. You would then be able to use that wallet to spend money that is under the control of private keys generated from the seed number that can be created from that phrase.

Bitcoin core does not support seed phrases at all.

Comment: OK  Thank you for the explanantion